# Multiple files for Doctrine Fixtures for Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, fixtures

I'm using the bundle Doctrine:Fixtures to load an example of bbdd throw the Entitys and since I work alone in the project it's ok.

But now, I got a colleague in my project and we were wondering if it's possible to set up a different files for the loading.

I got my own file of fixtures associated in git and I don't want him modifying this file. I would like to have an special file just for him that will allows him to modify whenever he wants this file of fixtures. So, anyone can have his owns records in the init of the bbdd.

If it's not possible with multiple files, could be possible in another way?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: Anyone can help? nobody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load specific fixture files using the `--fixture` flag:
`php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixture=/src/BundleName/DataFixtures/ORM/Fixture.php`

Or, you could add a `Fixtures.php.dist` file with some working examples, then use .gitignore to ignore `Fixtures.php`.

Then add a command into your build (or in composer scripts), and/or your documentation to copy this `.dist` file to `Fixtures.php` when checking out the project.

Another method if you're doing BDD is to create a Helper class that can be used in your `Context` to create and persist entities as you need them in tests. This would allow you to create only specifics needed for the test. All it really needs is the `EntityManager` so it may be simpler than pre-defining all the fixtures up front.

You can use [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to generate realistic entities.

```
class AbstractFixtureHelper implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Generator
     */
    protected $faker;

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->faker = Factory::create();
    }

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface|null $container
     * @return void
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    }
}
```

Then for different entities - in this example, a user:

```
class UserFixtureHelper extends AbstractFixtureHelper
{
    public function createUser()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail($this->faker->email);
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Then in your Context, inject the `UserFixtureHelper` and create directly in the scenario steps.

```
/**
* @Given there is a User who XXX
*/
public function thereIsAUser()
{
    $user = $this->userFixtureHelper->createUser();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your solutions are not what I'm searching for.

The first option the .dist does not make sense. I want all the different files of Fixtures.php inside git. I can only save one versions in the .dist but the rest will be out the git.

The second answer as I see is just to be able to create different kinds of records. What I want is different versions of records based on the same data tables but with values completely differents so I can swap between them whenever I want just using the file I want.

I would be able to have a different fixed configuration of records.

Comment: http://php-symfony.uk/doctrine-load-fixtures-how-to-load-particular-fixture/ ? Have added an update to the answer.

Comment: I'm srry to say you that... I already saw this option --fixtures that allows you to load another directory and aparently is the solution... but... I can't use this solution because in the newest version of this bundle with Symfony 3.4.7 this option does not appear.

I'm using Symfony 3.4.7 and doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle v1.3.1.

Do you know how to do the same you said in these versions?

Comment: You can use Groups to achieve it :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#fixture-groups-only-executing-some-fixtures